# Draw flip flop with Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, overleaf, logic

I'm trying to draw just one JK flip flop using Circuitikz, but Overleaf does not compile it properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{
% async
latch/.style={flipflop, flipflop def={t1=D, t6=Q, t3=CLK, 
t4=\ctikztextnot{Q}}},
flipflop SR/.style={flipflop, flipflop def={t1=S, t3=R, t6=Q, 
t4=\ctikztextnot{Q}}},
% sync
flipflop D/.style={flipflop, flipflop def={t1=D, t6=Q, c3=1, 
t4=\ctikztextnot{Q}}},
 flipflop T/.style={flipflop, flipflop def={t1=T, t6=Q, c3=1, 
t4=\ctikztextnot{Q}}},
flipflop JK/.style={flipflop,
flipflop def={t1=J, t3=K, c2=1, t6=Q, t4=\ctikztextnot{Q}}},
% additional features
add async SR/.style={flipflop def={%
tu={\ctikztextnot{SET}}, td={\ctikztextnot{RST}}}},
dot on notQ/.style={flipflop def={t4={Q}, n4=1}},
 }


 \begin{document}

 \begin{circuitikz}
  \draw 
  (0,0) node[flipflop JK]{JK}
  ;
  \end{circuitikz}

  \end{document}
```

I am following CircuiTikZ documentation but nothing comes clear.

Comment: Flip-flops have been added to `v1.0.0-pre1`. I did a fast check with `\pgfcircversion` and overleaf is still to 0.8.3, which is quite old. You need to download the `circuitikzgit.sty` file from https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/, add it to your project, and us it as explained in that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overleaf is using a stable, but quite old, versions of lot of TeX packages. In the case of `circuitikz`, as of today, the shipped version is 0.8.3, which is almost one and a half year old.

Fortunately, `circuitikz` provides a way to download whichever version you want as a single file. Go to the page https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/ and download the version you want (in this case, right-click on "version 1.0.10-pre1" and save it in your PC somewhere as `circuitikzgit.sty`).

Now you can upload it to overleaf, in the same directory as your project, and use it by changing the `\usepackage` from `circuitikz` to `circuitikzgit`.

[image: screenshot of an overleaf session]

BTW, if you are using the default version of the flip-flops, you do not need to re-define them as in your example.