# How could I write this in a more exportable way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

This figure I have drawn with Circuitikz is the very first "complex" one I have dealt with since the first stone, but I would like to know for future projects if it is possible to make it more "exportable", that is, if change the separation between FlipFlops, not many things will change position, unlike now.

This is what I have written:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}

\tikzset{flipflop JK/.style={flipflop,
flipflop def={t1=Q, t3={\ctikztextnot{Q}}, t6=J, t4=K,c5=1, td=PRST, 
tu=CLR},
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.8, transform shape]
        \node[vsourcesquareshape, rotate=90](clk){};
         \draw (-3,0) node[flipflop JK,external pins width=0](FF0){};
         \draw (-6,0) node[flipflop JK,external pins width=0](FF1){};
         \draw (-9,0) node[flipflop JK,external pins width=0](FF2){};
         \draw (-12,0) node[flipflop JK,external pins width=0](FF3){};
         \draw (-15,0) node[flipflop JK,external pins width=0](FF4){};

         \draw (clk.north) -- (FF0.east)node[inputarrow,rotate=180]{};
         \draw (FF0.pin 1) -| (-4.5,0);
         \draw (-4.5,0) -- (FF1.pin 5)node[inputarrow,rotate=180]{};

         \draw (FF1.pin 1) -| (-7.5,0);
         \draw (-7.5,0) -- (FF2.pin 5)node[inputarrow,rotate=180]{};

         \draw (FF2.pin 1) -| (-10.5,0);
         \draw (-10.5,0) -- (FF3.pin 5)node[inputarrow,rotate=180]{};

         \draw (FF3.pin 1) -| (-13.5,0);
         \draw (-13.5,0) -- (FF4.pin 5)node[inputarrow,rotate=180]{};

         \draw (FF0.pin 1) -| (-4.5,2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90] 
          {\rotatebox{-90}{$Q_0$}};
         \draw (FF1.pin 1) -| (-7.5,2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90] 
          {\rotatebox{-90}{$Q_1$}};
         \draw (FF2.pin 1) -| (-10.5,2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90] 
          {\rotatebox{-90}{$Q_2$}};
           \draw (FF3.pin 1) -| (-13.5,2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90] 
           {\rotatebox{-90}{$Q_3$}};
           \draw (FF4.pin 1) -| (-16.5,2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90] 
           {\rotatebox{-90}{$Q_4$}};

     \end{circuitikz}
   \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally the trick is using  less absolute positions. For example, you position the first flip flop, and then the other with, for example, `(FF1.center) ++(-3,0)`. You can even use a definition, like `\newcommand{\mydist}{-3}` and use it instead of the number. Then you name coordinates and use the `|-` syntax extensively. The second tutorial in the manual is written like this...

Comment: The Ti*k*Z `calc` library is also very useful.

Comment: You seem to be seeking the features of the `positioning` library. Well, I seem to have an old version of `circuitikzgit`, i.e. I get errors when I compile your file. Please *always* add the link to files that are not part of the standard TeX installations and get used in your document.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I think that the OP is using my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521545/draw-flip-flop-with-circuitikz --- flip-flops are the shiny latest addition (but they should have arrived via CTAN yesterday, oh oh oh :)

Comment: Yes this is correct, I just posted a new question unrelated to this and I specify where to dowload the release, Thank you Rmano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the question as the wish to make it easier to change some features of the circuit globally. This can be done by using `chains`, `\foreach` and, as pointed out by Rmano, calc. One can put the flip flops on a chain and do the rest in a loop. Then these parameters appear only once and can be changed globally. For instance, the distance between the flip flops is given by `node distance`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains}
\tikzset{flipflop JK/.style={flipflop,
flipflop def={t1=Q, t3={\ctikztextnot{Q}}, t6=J, t4=K,c5=1, td=PRST, 
tu=CLR},
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.8, transform shape]
         \node[vsourcesquareshape, rotate=90](clk){};
         % do the flip flops     
         \begin{scope}[start chain=going left,node distance=1.5cm,
            nodes={on chain,flipflop JK,external pins width=0}]
            \path foreach \X in {0,...,4}
            {node(FF\X){}};
         \end{scope}
         % determine the midpoints between the flip flops and name them
         \path foreach \X in {1,...,4}
          {(FF\the\numexpr\X-1|-0,0) -- coordinate (c\X) (FF\X|-0,0)};
         % add one more of the points to the left
         \path let \p1=($(FF0.center)-(c1)$) in (FF4.center|-0,0)
          ++ (-\x1,0) coordinate (c5);
         % from original code
         \draw (clk.north) -- (FF0.east)node[inputarrow,rotate=180]{};
         % draw the stuff between those nodes
         \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
         {\draw (FF\the\numexpr\X-1\relax.pin 1) -| (c\X);
          \draw (c\X) -- (FF\X.pin 5)node[inputarrow,rotate=180]{};
          \draw (FF\the\numexpr\X-1\relax.pin 1) -| (c\X|-0,2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90] 
          {\rotatebox{-90}{$Q_{\the\numexpr\X-1\relax}$}};}
         % use c5 
         \draw (FF4.pin 1) -| (c5|-0,2) node[inputarrow,rotate=90] 
            {\rotatebox{-90}{$Q_4$}};
     \end{circuitikz}
   \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Big thanks go to Rmano for instructing me how to run your code through. I am using the latest version of `circuitikz` on CTAN. And sorry, I cannot tell you how to get this on overleaf, nor do I know anything about fixing problems on overleaf.