# Draw circuit using circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am trying to replicate this circuit fully including the arrows on the outside and inside (KVL).

[image: Circuit]

Any help please would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a starting point.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.8,transform shape]
\draw (0,0) to[sV,l_=$240 \angle{0^\circ} \si{\volt}$,name=vf](0,1.5)to [L,l=$\mathrm{j}0.12\ \si{\ohm}$](0,2.5) to [R=$0.08\ \si{\ohm}$](0,4)to [short,-o](2,4);
\node at (2,4) [above]{A};
\draw (2,4)to [short](3,4) to [R,l=$0.2\ \si{\ohm}$](4.5,4)to[L,l=$\mathrm{j}0.5\ \si{\ohm}$](6,4)to [short,i=$I_A$,-o](6.5,4)to [short](7.5,4) to [short,i=$I_P$](7.5,3.5)to[R,l=$8\ \si{\ohm}$](7.5,2.25)to[L,l=$\mathrm{j}5\ \si{\ohm}$](7.5,1)to [short](7.5,0)to[short](0,0);
\draw[red,thick,rounded corners,-latex] (2,0.5)--(2,3.5)--++(0:4.5)--++(-90:2.9)--++(180:3.75)node[above]{KVL};
\node at (vf.45){$+$};
\draw (8.35,4) to [open,v^=$V_P$] (8.35,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you put the `o` pole in the second part of the circuit, like `\draw (2,4)to [short, o-](3,4) ...` you'll avoid the artifact on the node below A. Nice, +1

Comment: Try `\draw (8.35,0) to [open,v=$V_P$] (8.35,4);` or `\draw (8.35,0) to [open,v^=$V_P$] (8.35,4);`

Comment: @koxoso9363 --- overleaf has a very old `circuitikz`, 0.8.3, without the `RPvoltages` option. There is a big warning in the compilation log, I am sure, but overleaf do not sho warnings by default.

Comment: @koxoso9363 see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521554/38080; the voltage direction backward compatibility is quite a mess, please read the manual where it is extensively explained.

Comment: @koxoso9363, I am using `circuitikz` 1.0.0 (latest updated version) and not using overleaf.

Comment: @ferahfeza --- `1.0.0-pre1`, 1.0.0 has not been (yet) released.

Comment: @Rmano-- I meant `1.0.0-pre1` . Thank you.

Comment: @koxoso9363, your welcome. I will add Rmano's suggestion as soon as possible.

Comment: @ferahfeza For a starting point? :-):-) You have done all the circuit :-) +1

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you. An answer without much care, for this reason, it was a starting point.

Answer (score 7):

As supplement to @ferahfeza nice answer (+1). Used are

- `siunitx` syntax option
- redefined `siunitx` complex number notation
- relative coordinates
- redefined bipoles sizes
- slightly modified electric scheme
- used is recent `circuitikz` (version 1.0.0-pre1 (2019/12/22)) available on CTAN

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\sisetup{complex-root-position=before-number,
         output-complex-root=j}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=11mm}
\draw (0,0) to[sV, l_=$240\angle\ang{0}$\,V, name=V]  ++ (0,1.5) 
                                            node[below left] {$+$}
            to[L=j 0.12<\ohm>]  ++ (0,1.5)
            to[R=0.08<\ohm>]    ++ (0,1.5)
            to[short,-o]        ++ (1,0)    coordinate[label=A] (auxA)
%
            to[R=0.08<\ohm>]    ++ (1.5,0)
            to[short,i=$I_A$]   ++ (1,0)
            to[L=j0.12<\ohm>,-o]++ (1.5,0)  coordinate[label=B] (auxB)
%
            to[short]           ++ (1.0,0)
            to[R=8<\ohm>]       ++ (0,-2)
            to[short, i=$I_p$]  ++ (0,-0.5)
            to[L=j5<\ohm>]      ++ (0,-2)
            to[short,-o]        ++ (-1.0,0) coordinate[label=below:B'] (auxBB)
%
            to[short,-o]        ++ (-4,0)   coordinate[label=below:A'] (auxAA)
            to[short]   (0,0);
\draw[<->, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm]   
    (auxB) -- node[left] {$V_p$} (auxBB);
%
\draw[red,->, thick]
    (V.south east) |- ([shift={(0.5,-0.4)}] auxB)
                   |- ([xshift=9mm] V.south west) node[pos=0.75,above,text=black] {KVL};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good supplement, (+1).

Comment: Nice, but - the arrow for Vp is ambiguous (you should make the polarity ore use just one arrow), and you forgot the "V" (volts) measurement units on the generator ;-)... +1 from me.

Comment: @Rmano, thank you very much to point me on this.  Arrow is accidentally there, but on the unit I forgot :-(. I will try to resolve problem asap.

Comment: @Rmano, if I remember correctly, we already had discussion about `+` sign at alternating voltage source ;-). I add it to my answer regardless that I'm still convinced that this wrong. Apparently I can't accommodate myself to this habit. In time of my schooling we newer designate alternating voltage source on such a way :-)

Comment: @Zarko :-) sorry, I meant de designation of Vp, not the generator... You have a `<->` arrow so it's ambiguous, I do not know if Vp is VB-VB' or the other way around...