# Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'inner'

Tags: lyx, circuitikz, linux

I wrote my thesis in the Lyx software using Windows 10. At the end, i get a succesfully compiled PDF. I tried to compile the exact same document in Lyx in Linux but i get the error **Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'inner'** in any graphics that i made by using circuitikz package.

This graphics are electronic circuits that contains a transformer with his dots showing the polarity.
[image: circuit]

The code that i use for generate the previous circuit is:

```latex
%Preamble
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

%Flyback
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 1.5] \draw
    (0,0) node[transformer, yscale=1.5](T) {} 
    (T.A2)  
        to [short] ($(T.A2)+(-1.5,0)$)
        to [V, l=$V_S$, invert] ($(T.A1)+(-1.5,0)$)     
        to [nos, l=S] (T.A1)    
    (T.B1)
        to [D, l=D] ++(2,0) coordinate (Node1)  
        to [short] ++(2,0)
        to [R, l_=R, v^=$V_o$] ($(T.B2)+(4,0)$)
        to [short] (T.B2)
    (Node1)
        to [pC, l_=C, *-*, invert] ($(T.B2)+(2,0)$) 
    %Transformer labels
    (T.inner dot A1) node[circ]{}
    (T.inner dot B2) node[circ]{}
    ($(T.base)+(0,0.3)$) node{$N_1$ : $N_2$}
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Lyx says that this error ocurrs in these lines:

```latex
    (T.inner dot A1) node[circ]{}
    (T.inner dot B2) node[circ]{}
```

If i comment these lines that every circuit uses it, the error don't show but the dots for polarity neither.
How i can solve it? My code is the same, i just tried to compiled in Linux, no missing packages or similar.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Do you work with an up-to-date TeX installation?

Comment: One shortcut Ti*k*Z takes is that you can specify an explicit anchor by `(T.anchor)` or a point on the boarder by angle `(T.90)`. It is very likely that it does not find `inner dot A1` as an explicit anchor so it tries to parse it as an angle (which is a number). By doing so it throw everything into a pgfmathparse and immediately it finds that `inner` is not a valid function like `sin` and `exp`, hence the error.

Comment: Please add a `\pgfcircversion` in your text somewhere to see what the version is. `inner` anchors has been added around 0.9.2 and for example the stock Ubuntu 8.04 distribution has older packages. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521554/38080

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, yes i recently installed openSUSE with Lyx.

Comment: @Rmano i used the package manager of my distribution and found that both Miktex (Windows 10) and Linux uses the same 0.8.3 version.

Comment: `inner dot` was not in 0.8.3; it was added in 0.9.0. You can update the package with any release from [GitHub](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/releases) or (probably easier) using the method I explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521554/38080. In the page https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/ there are instructions on how to use any version you want!

Comment: I put a Q&A here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that/524329#524329