# Circuitikz; What should I do to put the + and - on the appropriate places like the pair on the picture?

Tags: circuitikz

I try to imitate the scale style of the text book (american style), so I modified the length of the bipoles, like this

`\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}`

Everything went smoothly except the symbol of + and - on the american voltage source, they were mixed together, like this

[image]

An example is this 
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[americanvoltages,americancurrents,
americanresistors,americaninductors,
europeanports,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}
    \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to[V,invert,v<=$\dot{U_S}$] (0,2.5) 
            to[L=$\mr{j}\omega L$] (2,2.5) 
            to[short,i=$\dot{I}_C$] (4,2.5) 
            to[C=$1/\mr{j}\omega C$] (4,0) to (0,0);
            \draw (2,2.5) to[R=$R$,*-*] (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The good news is that circuitikz provides `volatage/american font`, `voltage/american plus` and `voltage/american minus` to set the symbols.  The bad news is that changing them doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Ronan So you want to put a plus above a minus but they're meshing together?

Comment: Could you show a small complete document that produces the output you show in your question?

Comment: @Someonne Exactly.

Comment: @Marijn I have put my code above, thank you for your attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supported way to change the relative size of components is to use the class keys `resistors/scale`, `capacitors/scale` and so on. Once you have the relative scales correct, using a global `scale=xxx, transform shape` will give you the sizes you like.

The `V` symbol (really `vsourceam`) has the `+` and `-` symbol drawn with the current font, and it's not adjustable. Look:

```latex
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.7} 
\ctikzset{capacitors/scale=0.7} 
\ctikzset{sources/scale=0.9} 

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V, l_=$\hat{U}(s)$] ++(0,3) to[R=\SI{5}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
      to[C=$1/j\omega C$] ++(0,-3) to[short, -*] (0,0)
      node[ground]{};
      \tiny
      \draw (5,0) to[V, l_=$\hat{U}(s)$] ++(0,3) to[R=\SI{5}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
      to[C=$1/j\omega C$] ++(0,-3) to[short, -*] (0,0)
      node[ground]{};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image: result of the snippet above]

If you want to be able to change the font you have to add the configurability to the component (hey, I think I'll add it to the next version):

```latex
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
%% Redefine vsourceam to have + and - customizable
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus/.initial={$+$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus/.initial={$-$}}
%% Independent voltage source - American style
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{sources}
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}
{vsourceAM}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/width}}
{

    \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
    \pgf@circ@draworfill
    \pgfsetcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
    \ifpgf@circ@oldvoltagedirection
    \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@up]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus}}
    \else
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@down]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@up]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus}}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.7}
\ctikzset{capacitors/scale=0.7}
\ctikzset{sources/scale=0.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V, l_=$\hat{U}(s)$] ++(0,3) to[R=\SI{5}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
      to[C=$1/j\omega C$] ++(0,-3) to[short, -*] (0,0)
      node[ground]{};
   \ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={\tiny $+$}}
   \ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={\tiny $-$}}
   \draw (5,0) to[V, l_=$\hat{U}(s)$] ++(0,3) to[R=\SI{5}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
   to[V, invert, bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={\color{red}\tiny $\oplus$},
        bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={}] ++(0,-3)
   to[short, -*] (0,0)
      node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: These options will be in `circuitikz` v1.0.3 and forward. See https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/387

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a novice in circuitikz. I just can't simply load the `RPvoltages` option of the circuitikz package, and  texstudio can't run some other commands either. Did I forgot something? Like the settings in texstudio?

Comment: @Ronan TeXstudio is just an editor, not a TeX/LaTeX system. But your problem is that you probably have an old version of circuitikz. You can see it by loading the package and putting the command `\pgfcircversion` somewhere in your code. You can find uptodate version at https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that

Comment: Finally did I figure it out. Thank you for your considerable help! Hope you can add it to the next version as soon as possible.

Comment: It's already in the `...git` version. I have two big merges now, then I will release a version, I hope this weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:  The following **should** work (or at least have **some** effect), but doesn't.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}
\ctikzset{voltage/american font=\tiny}
\ctikzset{voltage/american plus=X}
\ctikzset{voltage/american minus=O}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[american voltage source,l=$U_z$] (0,2);
\node[below] at (current bounding box.south) {\csname pgf@circ@avplus\endcsname};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, these keys are for the external voltages (the ones with `v=...`) keys. The + and + of the generator are set with the current font (that's suboptimal, yes, I know).