# Drawing flip-flops

Tags: circuitikz

How can I draw flip-flops and why doesn't this work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (3,0) node[flipflop JK, add async SR, rotate=90]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works here. Do you have the log file?

Comment: Hi, welcome. It works fine for me as well, though I have no idea if the output makes sense. What exactly do you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/flipflop JK' and I am going to ignore it
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/add async SR' and I am going to ignore it

Comment: I see in the `circuitikz` manual that flipflops were added in version 1.0.0, so if you have an older version you need to upgrade. You can check the version with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{circuitikz} \begin{document} \pgfcircversion \end{document}`. How exactly you can update the package, if that is what's needed, depends on which TeX distribution you have installed (MikTeX, TeX Live, MikTeX).

Comment: I use overleaf and when i type \pgfcircversion don't get anything on screen

Comment: Are you sure? I get 0.9.7. Overleaf currently doesn't have anything newer than TeX Live 2019, which doesn't have v1 of `circuitikz`, so apart from waiting until they make TL 2020 available (they're working on it, but I don't know when that will happen), I would guess you have to manually upload all the files for `circuitikz` v1 to your project to make the code in your question work. Which is a bit inconvenient, and there are multiple files.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it's a bit of a hack, but you can do that with a single file (plus a style file if you need/want it). I have it explained in the Q&A linked above.