# CircuiTikZ Manual Ex: 9.9 3-phases block schematic

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to integrate some parts of the Ex: 9.9 3-phases block schematic (from the CircuiTikZ 1.1.2 - manual) into my own schematic. However, I'm unable to even reproduce the results of the Ex, let alone be able to take the components of interest such as the "oosourcetrans,prim=wye,sec=delta,l=transformer".

If you would be kind enough, please help me debug my own code, as well as, point out why I'm not able to see the results of the schema in the manual when I run its code.

The link to the manual: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf

**pg 166 or 9.9 3-phases block schematic**

Thank you in advance!

My code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,americanvoltage,smartlabels,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}


\begin{circuitikz}[smallR/.style={european resistor, resistors/scale=0.5}]
\draw
(0,0) node[gridnode,anchor=left] (m) {}
to[oosourcetrans,prim=wye,sec=delta,l=transformer]++(2.5,0)
++(-0.8,0) 
(2.5,-0.05) node[inputarrow,rotate=90] {} --
 ++(0,-0.8) node[adcshape,box,anchor=north, fill=orange] {}
 ++(-1.8,0)
(2.5,-1.85) node[inputarrow,rotate=90] {} --
 ++(0,-0.8) node[twoportshape,t=PC,box,anchor=north] {}
 ++(1.8,0) 
(2.5,0.05) node[inputarrow,rotate=-90] {} --
 ++(0,0.8) node[dacshape,box,anchor=south, fill=orange] {};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You do not say which is the error you have. Your circuit compile fine here. Are you sure is not a case of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that?