# LaTeX CircuiTikZ I do not know the key '/tikz/tr circle'

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, pgfkeys, circles

I am learning LaTeX, and i was trying  to follow some examples, and i came across this one from `CircuiTikZ`
[image]

```latex
\begin{circuitikz}[]
\draw (0,2) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){};
\ctikzset{transistor circle/relative thickness=2}
\draw (2,2) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){};
\ctikzset{transistor circle/color=red}
\draw (0,0) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){};
\ctikzset{transistor circle/color=default}
\ctikzset{transistor circle/dash={{4pt}{4pt}{1pt}{4pt}}}
\draw[color=blue] (2,0) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){};
\end{circuitikz}
```

I am using OverLeaf

[image]

As you can see, there is no cirle arround the transistors
and this error shows up `I do not know the key '/tikz/tr circle' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

I have read the documentation and searched online and cant find anything.
Do you have any idea why this is not working?

Here is the total code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
\draw (0,2) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){};
\ctikzset{transistor circle/relative thickness=2}
\draw (2,2) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){};
\ctikzset{transistor circle/color=red}
\draw (0,0) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){};
\ctikzset{transistor circle/color=default}
\ctikzset{transistor circle/dash={{4pt}{4pt}{1pt}{4pt}}}
\draw[color=blue] (2,0) node[npn, tr circle](Q1){};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tr circle` is very new --- probably overleaf has an older release. You can check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that

Comment: `tr circle` has been added in version 1.2.6 (2020-12-16), so it's highly improbable that overleaf has it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

This is the situation at `overleaf` as of today:

[image]

If you check at https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf (Changelog and Release Notes, near the end) you'll see that the `tr circle` was introduced in 1.2.6.

You can follow the instruction at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524329/38080 to use a newer version of `circuitikz` on overleaf.

BTW the above figure was generated with:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\today{}:
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    Tikz:& \pgfversion & \pgfversiondate\\
    Pgfplots:& \pgfplotsversion & \pgfplotsversiondate \\
    Circuitikz:& \pgfcircversion & \pgfcircversiondate\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you fo the help. it was exactly that, i added the most recent `CircuiTikZ` package and worked perfectly