# Anchor of a push-button switch

Tags: circuitikz

My electrical circuit contains a push button (I took for the drawing a normally open): in the documentation, I saw that an anchor was possible for such `tip` switches

So I tried using it to see but the following code gives me an error "Package PGF Math Error : Unknown fonction tip in (tip).

Is it because `tip` is not an anchor or is it because I am misusing it?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, european, straightvoltages, cute inductors]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[nopb, name=S] (2,0);
\draw [->, red, very thick] ($(S.tip)+(0.5,0)$) --++(-0.5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
                
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is your `circuitikz` version? That anchor was added in version 1.2.6.

With 1.3.4 it works and compiles into:

[image]

as expected... you can check my answer here: [I need to use a different version of circuitikz. How can I do that?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that)

BTW you can obtain the same by

```latex
    \draw [<-, red, very thick] (S.tip) -- ++(0.5,0);
```

that is, just reversing the arrow direction.

Comment: My version was inferior : with the update it works thank you