# nobase/nogate not working for nigbt in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I want to disable the gate connection for IGBT but 'nogate/nobase' isn't working as its for transistor class.
Is there any other command that will help be get rid of the gate terminal of IGBT?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 

\draw
(0,0) to[sinusoidal voltage source,l=$v_{s}$]++(0,3)
(0,3) to[inductor,l=L,i=$i_L$]++(3,0) 
(4,3) node[nigbt,bodydiode,rotate=90,scale=-1,nobase]{}   
(5,3)node[nigbt,bodydiode,rotate=90,nogate]{} 

;


\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: circuit]

Comment: Hmm. From a cursory look at the source, the `nobase/nogate` option is not supported for `[np]igbt` and company. Maybe worth a feature request on https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues (no promises though, I am quite busy lately... but I'll look into it when I can)

Comment: You could just cover it up with a thicker white line.

Comment: Will be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/589

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem has been fixed starting from version 1.4.4**, released on October 31, 2021.

**For older versions**
This is clearly a stopgap option, and I have not tested at all more than on your snippet, so take it with caution. This is a redefinition of the `nigbt` and company to take into account the `nogate/nobase` option. Just add everything between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` into the preamble of your document, *after* loading `cicuitikz`.

**Notice that I fixed the `nobase` anchor position in this second version**

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\long\def\declareigbt#1{
    \pgfcircdeclaretransistor{#1}{
        \anchor{inner up}{
            \northeast
            \pgf@y=\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height}\pgf@y
        }
        \anchor{inner down}{
            \northeast
            \pgf@y=-\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height}\pgf@y
        }
        \anchor{nobase}{
           \left
           \pgf@x=\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate width}\pgf@x
        }
    }
    {
        % add the circle if requested (before everything else, so we can fill it)
        \pgfcirc@transistorcircle
        % fill the gap color if requested
        \pgfcirc@fillgategap{#1}
        %draw upper connection
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+\pgfverticaltransformationadjustment*.5*\pgflinewidth}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}
        {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
            {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height 2}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}

        %draw thicker gate lines
        \pgfscope
            \pgfscope
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/outer base height}\pgf@circ@res@up+\pgfverticaltransformationadjustment*.5\pgflinewidth}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/outer base height}\pgf@circ@res@down-\pgfverticaltransformationadjustment*.5\pgflinewidth}}
                % set the normal thickness
                \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{tripoles}{\pgflinewidth}
                \edef\@@extrat{\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/outer base thickness}}
                \pgfsetlinewidth{\@@extrat\pgflinewidth}
                \pgfusepath{draw}
            \endpgfscope
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
            {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/base height}\pgf@circ@res@up+\pgfverticaltransformationadjustment*.5\pgflinewidth}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
            {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/base height}\pgf@circ@res@down-\pgfverticaltransformationadjustment*.5\pgflinewidth}}
            \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{tripoles}{\pgflinewidth}
            \pgfusepath{draw}
        \endpgfscope
        %draw lower connection
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
            {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height 2}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}
        {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down-\pgfverticaltransformationadjustment*.5*\pgflinewidth}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        %draw arrow depending on type of transistor
        \pgfscope
            \pgfslopedattimetrue
            \pgfallowupsidedownattimetrue
            \pgfresetnontranslationattimefalse
            \ifpgf@circuit@trans@arrowatend
                \ifpgf@circuit@trans@ntype
                    \edef\@@anchor{btip}\edef\@@pos{1.0}
                \else
                    \edef\@@anchor{tip}\edef\@@pos{1.0}
                \fi
            \else
                \edef\@@anchor{center}\edef\@@pos{0.5}
            \fi
            \ifpgf@circuit@trans@ntype
                \pgftransformlineattime{\@@pos}{%
                    \pgfpoint%
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}%
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height 2}\pgf@circ@res@down}%
                    }{%
                    \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}%
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@down}%
                }
            \else
                \pgftransformlineattime{\@@pos}{%
                    \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}%
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@up}%
                    }{%
                    \pgfpoint{\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}%
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate height 2}\pgf@circ@res@up}%
                }
            \fi
            \pgfnode{trarrow}{\@@anchor}{}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}
        \endpgfscope
        %draw gate
        \ifpgf@circuit@bpt@drawgate
            \ifpgf@circuit@trans@ntype
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/conn height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment*.5*\pgflinewidth}%
                {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/conn height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
            \else
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                    {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/conn height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment*.5*\pgflinewidth}%
                {\ctikzvalof{tripoles/#1/conn height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \fi
            \pgfusepath{draw}
        \fi
    }
}

\declareigbt{pigbt}
\declareigbt{nigbt}
\declareigbt{Lnigbt}
\declareigbt{Lpigbt}


\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw
            (0,0) to[sinusoidal voltage source,l=$v_{s}$]++(0,3)
            (0,3) to[inductor,l=L,i=$i_L$]++(3,0)
            (4,3) node[nigbt,bodydiode,rotate=90,scale=-1,nobase]{}
            (5,3)node[nigbt,bodydiode,rotate=90,nogate]{}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Really the only change is to surround the gate drawing with `\ifpgf@circuit@bpt@drawgate...\fi`, but I can't come up with a simpler patch now... so this is a brute force approach. It will be in the next version of `circuitikz`.

There is a fix for the next version. As soon as it is merged, you can use the trick described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524329/38080 to download the "cutting edge" `circuitikzgit.sty`.

Comment: Thank you!
just getting one error, if you could help me with that as well
`! Undefined control sequence.\pgf@sh@bg@nigbt ...orcircle \pgfcirc@fillgategap{nigbt} \pgfpathmoveto {\p... (`   in `(4,3) node[nigbt,bodydiode,rotate=90,scale=-1,nobase]{}
            (5,3)node[nigbt,bodydiode,rotate=90,nogate]{}`

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of circuitikz (1.3.4)? The solution will not work with anything older.

Comment: Oh sorry,I'm using 5.0.4

Comment: `circuitikz` 5.0.4 does not exist... at this pace, it's due for 2080 ;-P

Comment: Sorry, the latest version is 1.4.3, no 1.3.4 (typo!)