# How can I fix the issues in this circuit?

Tags: formatting, diagrams, circuitikz, alignment, circuits

I’m writing this circuit, but I can get the output of `A0` wired to the input `A2.+`, and at the output $V_o$ I can’t get the label above the scope and can’t change the signal at the scope. I have tested with

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/waveform=square}
\draw (7,-3) node[oscopeshape,fill=blue](O){};
```

based on the [CircuiTikZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CircuiTikZ) manual 1.4.13 section 4.6.1.1 Oscilloscope waveform.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzsetstyle{romano}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
\draw (-4,-5.5) node [op amp](A0){\texttt{OA0}};
\draw (A0.-) to[short] ++(0,1) coordinate(tmp) to[R, l_=$R$] (tmp -| A0.out) to[short] (A0.out);
%\draw (tmp) to[short] ++(0,1) coordinate(tmp) to[C=$C$] (tmp -| A0.out) to[short] (A0.out);
\draw (A0.+) to [R, l_=$R1$ ] ++(0,-2.5) node[ground](GND){};
\draw (A0.-) to [short, ] ++  to [C=$C2$](-7,-5.025) -|(-7,0.5){};
%\draw (A0.out) --  (A2.+);
%\draw (A0.out) to[short,-]++ (1,0)  (A2.+);

    \draw (0,0) node[op amp, noinv input up](A1){\texttt{A1}}
    (A1.+) to[short, -] ++(-8,0) coordinate(ainst-) node[left]{$V_i$}
    (A1.-) to [short, -o] ++(0,-1) coordinate (ra-up);
    \draw (ra-up) to[vR, l_=$R_A$, name=RA0, o-o] ++(0,-2) coordinate (ra-down);
    \draw (ras-down) to [short, o-] ++(0,-1) node[op amp, anchor=-](A2){\texttt{A2}}
    (A2.+) to[short, -] (A2.+ -| ainst-) coordinate(ainst+) node[left]{$$}
    (ra-up) to[R, l_=$R_B$, name=RB1, o-] (ra-up -| A1.out) coordinate(vup) -- (A1.out)
    (ra-down) to[R=$R_B$, name=RB2] (ra-down -| A2.out) coordinate(vdn) -- (A2.out)
    ;

    \draw (vdn) to[R=$R$, name=R1] ++(2,0) node[op amp, anchor=+](A3){\texttt{A3}}
    (A3.+) to[R=$R$, -, name=R2] ++(0,-2) ++(0,0) node[ground]{}
    (vup) to[R=$R$, name=R3] (A3.- |- vup) coordinate(a3fb) --(A3.-)
    (a3fb) to [R=$R$, name=R4] (A3.out |- a3fb) -- (A3.out)
    to [short, -] ++(1,0) node[down]{$V_o$}
    ;

\ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/waveform=square}
\draw (7,-3) node[oscopeshape,fill=blue](O){};
(2,0.65) node[anchor=base]{pulse};
\draw (-8,0.5)
to[oscope=$C_1$, fill=green!20!gray, name=O1] ++(2,0);
%\path (O1.right) to [short] {A1.+};
\ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/width=1.0}
\draw (10,-50)
node[oscopeshape, fill=yellow!20!orange](O2){$C_2$};
\draw (O2.in 2) to[short, *-] ++(0,-0.5) node[ground]{};
\draw (O2.in 1) to[short, *-] ++(0,-0.5)
-- ++(-1,0) node[currarrow, xscale=-1]{};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

As noted by js bibra, I was misspelling some keywords, but then at compilation it reports these errors:

```
! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.
 \draw (A0.-) to [short] ++  t
                                  o [C=$C2$](-7,-5.025) -|(-7,0.5){};

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/oscope
/waveform', to which you passed 'square', and I am going to ignore it.


! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
               there is probably something wrong with the class file.
```

Comment: you are using `ras-down` instead of `ra-down` in certain places

Comment: Let me check, perhaps I miss observed the code.

Comment: The first error is that you can't have `to[] ++ to[]` --- you missed a coordinate there, like `to[] ++(2,0) to[]...`. The second one is because you probably have a too old version (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/524328/38080). The last one is probably a secondary effect of some other error...

Comment: I come here from hot network questions and I thought it was an electronics engineering question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

More or less I write your circuit scheme from scratch:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzsetstyle{romano}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (-4,-5.5)   node [op amp](A) {\texttt{OA0}} 
        (A.-)       to[short]   ++  (0,1) coordinate(auxA1) 
                    to[R=$R$]       (auxA1 -| A.out) -- (A.out) 
        (A.+)       to[R=$R1$]  ++  (0,-2) node[ground] {} 
        (A.-)       to[C=$C2$]  ++  (-2,0) coordinate (auxA2) 
% 
        (A.out)     -- ++   (1,0) node[op amp, anchor=+] (B) {\texttt{A2}}        
        (B.-)       -- ++   (0,1)                       coordinate(auxB1)
                    to[R=$R_B$, o-] (auxB1 -| B.out)    coordinate(auxB2)
                    -- (B.out) 
%
        (auxB1)     to[vR=$R_A$, mirror, -o] ++ (0,2)            coordinate (C1)
                    -- ++   (0,1) 
                    node[op amp, noinv input up, anchor=-] (C) {\texttt{A1}}
        (C1)        to[R=$R_B$]     (C1 -| C.out)       coordinate (C2)
                    -- (C.out)
% input
        (auxA2 |- C.+)  node[oscopeshape,fill=teal!30,label=$C_1$] (osc) {}
                    to[short,-o]    ++ (-1,0)   node[left] {$V_i$}
        (osc)       -- (C.+)  
        (osc)       -- (auxA2)
% output op amp
        (auxB2)     to[R=$R$]   ++ (2,0)   
                    node[op amp, anchor=+] (D) {\texttt{A3}}
        (C2)        to[R=$R$]   (C2 -| D.-)             coordinate (D1)
                    -- (D.-)
        (D.+)       to[R=$R$]   ++ (0,-2)   node[ground] {} 
        (D1)        to[R=$R$]   (C2 -| D.out) 
                    -- (D.out);                    
\ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/waveform=square}
\draw   (D.out)     -- ++ (1,0) 
                    node[oscopeshape,fill=blue!30,label=$V_o$] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is it. Thanks a lot, I have to study your code to address the errors. More or less? You write down the circuit exactly as it should be!! =)

Answer (score 3):

so far so good I think

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzsetstyle{romano}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
        \draw (-4,-5.5) node [op amp](A0){\texttt{OA0}};
        \draw (A0.-) to[short] ++(0,1) coordinate(tmp) to[R, l_=$R$] (tmp -| A0.out) to[short] (A0.out);
        \draw (A0.+) to [R, l_=$R1$ ] ++(0,-2.5) node[ground](GND){};
        \draw (0,0) node[op amp, noinv input up](A1){\texttt{A1}}
        (A1.+) to[short, -] ++(-8,0) coordinate(ainst-) node[left]{$V_i$}
        (A1.-) to [short, -o] ++(0,-1) coordinate (ra-up);
        \draw (ra-up) to[vR, l_=$R_A$, name=RA0, o-o] ++(0,-2) coordinate (ra-down);
        \draw (ra-down) to [short, o-] ++(0,-1.03) node[op amp, anchor=-](A2){\texttt{A2}}
        (A2.+) to (A0.out)
        (ra-up) to[R, l_=$R_B$, name=RB1, o-] (ra-up -| A1.out) coordinate(vup) -- (A1.out)
        (ra-down) to[R=$R_B$, name=RB2] (ra-down -| A2.out) coordinate(vdn) -- (A2.out);
        \draw (vdn) to[R=$R$, name=R1] ++(2,0) node[op amp, anchor=+](A3){\texttt{A3}}
        (A3.+) to[R=$R$, -, name=R2] ++(0,-2) ++(0,0) node[ground]{}
        (vup) to[R=$R$, name=R3] (A3.- |- vup) coordinate(a3fb) --(A3.-)
        (a3fb) to [R=$R$, name=R4] (A3.out |- a3fb) -- (A3.out)
        to [short, -] ++(1,0) node[right]{$V_o$};


    \end{circuitikz}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, Im working with the scope parts but, I cant find out how to work it. And by the way , why cant connect AO0.out to A2.+?

Comment: @corie Probably because you draw the line *before* drawing the node. // Also you should also explain what did the op do wrong instead of just post the code...

Comment: @user202729, Hum, yes, it seems I did it backwards, I'll take in consideration, but Im sure I explained it (I mean , I remember to have posted the issue with the opamp).

Comment: @corie That part was for the answerer

Comment: @user202729, got it, thanks!