# Error compiling when I use "circuitikz" package. Error message: !Undefined control sequence \pgfutil@protected

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm having some problems with "circuitikz" package. When I try to use it TexStudio gives me the following error Undefined control sequence. \pgfutil@proteced. The code works correctly but when I call "circuitikz" something goes wrong.
I use MikTex as compiler and TexMaker as editor. I tryed to install the package many times but nothing.

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{article} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={.}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pbox}  


\begin{document}
Hi all, Hi all !
\end{document}
```

This code comes from another user who uses it without problems.
I ask for some advice because I tryed almost everything I found on the net.

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: It works fine in my computer (with the edit I made, changing the second `\begin{document}` for `\end{document}` which I suppose was a typo). It throws an unrelated warning about the pgfplots compat, btw.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your problem. BTW, package `amsmath` you load twice, `hyperref` should be loaded last. You may consider to upgrade your LaTeX installation.

Comment: You probably have a old version of `circuitikz`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that, or a too old version of Ti*k*Z.

Comment: In fact, I use the same code on another PC and it works like a charm! I'll try to update miktek at all.

Comment: Remeber also that to have externalize work you should not use `\begin{circuitikz}...\end{circuitikz}`, but  `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` (which really is exactly the same).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to use a different version of circuitikz. How can I do that?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that)

Comment: After reinstalling the entire Miktek , everything works well! Case closed !

Comment: @Rmano newer versions of `circuitikz` use `\pgfutil@protected` (the PRs done by me), whereas older versions of `pgf`/Ti*k*Z don't provide it (the switch made there to use `\pgfutil@protected` is relatively young, iirc). But anyways, the issue is (or was, as it now seems fixed) certainly mismatched package versions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...

Comment: @skillmon yes, it's supposed to work always but maybe the "right" combination of circuitikz version and Tikz version can cause it.

Comment: @Rmano would be a fairly recent version of `circuitikz` and a hopelessly out of date version of `pgf`.... :)