# Circuitikz (the new version 2020/02/05) not recognizing node names

Tags: circuitikz

My problem is straightforward, I copied the below code from the package and ran the code, but I keep getting the attached error in the picture.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}[=2020/02/05]
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
 (0,0) node[mixer] (mix) {}
 (mix.w) node[left] {w}
 (mix.s) node[below] {s}
(mix.e) node[right] {e}
(mix.n) node[above] {n};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another code that is not working, the nodes should not connect the way it appears in the figure.

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
 (0,0) node[mixer] (mix) {}
 (mix.east) to node[adder,right] (add) {}++(4,0)
 (mix.south) to node[oscillator,below] (osc) {}++(0,-2) ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

I actually tried to load all versions to see which one can solve the problem, but no one dose (please check my snapshot)

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: Use `article` class or other standard class for an MWE, it sets up all the usual document  settings; `minimal` class is intended for testing package-loading dependencies, and is literally minimal (3 lines of code). Eg: minimal class gives this error message: `Environment figure undefined.`.

Comment: remove `[=2020/02/05].` and use recent version of `circuitikz`. Old version doesnt have defined anchors `w`, `s`, `e` and `n` or instead them use `west`, `south` and `east) north˙`.

Comment: You probably have an old `circuitikz` package documentation. In recent one is not such example, only is mentioned how you can rollback to use older package version. Apparently tis old version doesn't has defined such syntax for denote shape anchors.

Comment: BTW, the recent `circuitikz` version is `1.4.6 (2022/02/04)`.

Comment: There is no such a syntax as `to node...` in circuitikz. Where you did find it? You probably mean `(mix.east) -- ++(4,0) node[adder, right](add){}`?

Comment: Maybe something else needs to be upgraded

Comment: @Diana, you have an old circuitikz version. You can check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that. Add `node {\pgfcircversion}` somewhere in your paths and check the version you have installed - you can go in the past with versions but not in the future 

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite confused; let's see ---

1. Asking for the version current on 2020/02/05 you are asking `circuitikz` to go back to version 1.0 (you can check that [here](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/)), which effectively had not the short anchors on blocks (they were added in 1.2.3, it's commented in the manual)
2. The syntax `to node[]...`, although existing in Ti*k*Z, has different effects than you think. No time now to explain what happens, you can make another question maybe?
3. When in doubt, you can always add something to your drawing to print the current version of `circuitikz` you have installed; I added a node in the last line to show it.

So probably you wanted this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw
    (0,0) node[mixer] (mix) {}
    (mix.w) node[left] {w}
    (mix.s) node[below] {s}
    (mix.e) node[right] {e}
    (mix.n) node[above] {n};
    \draw (2,0) node[mixer] (mix) {}
    (mix.east) -- ++(4,0) node[adder,right] (add) {}
    (mix.south) -- ++(0,-2) node[oscillator,below] (osc) {};
    % this draw command is just to print the installed version of circuitikz
    \draw (0,-1) node[draw, right, red, font=\ttfamily]
        {Circuitikz \pgfcircversion{} released \pgfcircversiondate};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]