# Circuitikz: How can I specify the direction of rotation for a label?

Tags: circuitikz

The following MWE rotates the label by +90°. How can I achieve rotation by -90° without changing the direction of the drawn path?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages,americanvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[R,l={\mbox{$R=\SI{50}{\ohm}$}},label/align=rotate] (0,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also `l_={...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just `circuitikz`, you can't; label directions are fixed, and try to follow the stroke direction when using `rotate`, in the same way the `sloped` Ti*k*Z option work. But you can (being careful about the rotation center, and about protecting the `[align=c]` from the Ti*k*Z parser), do this:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx} % siunitx option to circuitikz will load it, also
%\usepackage{tikz}% circuitikz will load it
\usepackage[european, americanvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{label/align=rotate}
    \draw (0,0) to[R,l={\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$R=\SI{50}{\ohm}$}}] (0,-2);
    \draw[red] (2,0) to[R,l={$R=\SI{50}{\ohm}$}] (2,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also removed the (confusing, and useless) `straightvoltages`, which is overridden by `americanvoltages`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't manage to compile it due to the ````origin=c```` option.

Comment: Probably you have an old `circuitikz`: check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that, you need something better than 1.3 more or less (I do not have time to check exactly). Or you can add an `\mbox` around the `\rotatebox` command, maybe)

Comment: Should work since version 1.3.0, released on January 2019.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try an update.

Comment: With ````circuitikz```` updated, it works like a charm. Thanks again!