# How can I remove the current arrow in ciruitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

This is my LaTex code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
  (5,0) to [resistor, l = 6.13k$\Omega$, v >= 5.13V] 
  (5,3) to [battery, l=10<\volt>] (-1,3) --
  (-1,0) -- (1,0) to [thR, l = $NTC$] (3,0) -- (5,0)
   (0,0) to [short,*-](0,-2) to[resistor, l = $R_P$] (4,-2) to  [short,-*](4,0)
%  (-1,-1) -- (0,-1)
  
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This is what I got from the code.

The arrow which I want to removed has been marked by red pen.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I have just did what you have asked!. Please take a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your code:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/v >
```

because the space within `v` and `>` is significant.

Anyway, the arrow shown is not a current arrow; it's a voltage one --- you are using the default, `european` way of marking voltages. Maybe you want the American notation:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages] \draw
  (5,0) to [resistor, l = 6.13k$\Omega$, v>= 5.13V]
  (5,3) to [battery, l=10<\volt>] (-1,3) --
  (-1,0) -- (1,0) to [thR, l = $NTC$] (3,0) -- (5,0)
   (0,0) to [short,*-](0,-2) to[resistor, l = $R_P$] (4,-2) to  [short,-*](4,0)
%  (-1,-1) -- (0,-1)

;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Moreover, as an addition, it's better to use `siunitx` all over, and using math-mode only when there is a math formula (in your case, you want NTC in italic, it's not N multiplied T multiplied C):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages] \draw
        (5,0) to [resistor, l = \qty{6.13}{\kohm}, v>= \qty{5.13}{V}]
        (5,3) to [battery, l=\qty{10}{V}] (-1,3) --
        (-1,0) -- (1,0) to [thR, l = \textit{NTC}] (3,0) -- (5,0)
   (0,0) to [short,*-](0,-2) to[resistor, l = $R_P$] (4,-2) to  [short,-*](4,0)
%  (-1,-1) -- (0,-1)

;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The difference is subtle, but it's there.

Finally, if you do not want any marking, that means this is not a voltage, just a generic annotation:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages] \draw
        (5,0) to [resistor, l=\qty{6.13}{\kohm}, a=\qty{5.13}{V}]
        (5,3) to [battery, l=\qty{10}{V}] (-1,3) --
        (-1,0) -- (1,0) to [thR, l = \textit{NTC}] (3,0) -- (5,0)
   (0,0) to [short,*-](0,-2) to[resistor, l = $R_P$] (4,-2) to  [short,-*](4,0)
%  (-1,-1) -- (0,-1)

;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember, the idea here is to *describe* the circuit and separate the graphical representation from the semantic meaning. So if you specify a voltage, the package will show that this is a voltage (depending on the options, with an arrow or with signs). If you want just an annotation, you use it.

Comment: can you remove +_ sign in the picture?
https://i.imgur.com/cZdyDko.png

Comment: Then it's not a voltage marking: you can try with an annotation `a=\qty{5.13}{V}` (added to the answer)

Comment: I have an error
`! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfk@/tikz/circuitikz/bipole/annotation/name ... `

Comment: I got the above error when I use your `a=\qty{5.13}{V}`

Comment: This is not your complete error... so I can't imagine what's failing. Do you have a recent version of `siunitx` *and* of `circuitikz`? Try with `a=\SI{5.13}{V}`, or check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that (but you should have a *very* old version of circuitikz to have an error here). Have you checked your syntax?

Comment: I had installed TexLive in 2019. `a=\SI{5.13}{V}` works !