# Package PGF Math Error in Circuit

Tags: circuitikz

Here is code I copied from official document. I got the following error.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw    
(0,0) node[mixer] (m) {}
(m.w) to[short,-o] ++(-1,0)
(m.s) to[short,-o] ++(0,-1)
(m.e) to[short,-o] ++(1,0)
(m.w) node[inputarrow] {}
(m.s) node[inputarrow,rotate=90] {};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The error is the following

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown
> function `w' (in 'w').

Comment: I get no error in texlive 2022. Show where you got the example, and your log with version numbers

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use textlive2019

Comment: and your example code comes from a 2019 document?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sure. How can I find document for 2019?  Any links? BTW, do you know how I can update my packages without re-installing textlive?

Comment: You must know where you found it? In any case on overleaf it works on 2022 and 2021 but not 2020 or older.

Comment: Unless you are very confident managing non-standard tex installs I would not install a new package in to texlive 2019, you are then in an un-tested, unsupportable configuration  and quite likely to get further package conflicts from pgf or expl3 or siunitx or all of them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you know where I can find manuals for 2019 `circuitikz` package? I have tried to find but no success.

Comment: The contracted names for mixer anchors are new. Use `west`, `north`, etc. Or upgrade... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that

Comment: All the versions of `circuitikz` with their manual and style files are here: https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz

Comment: you should have the manual on your machine, `texdoc circuitikz `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the  short form of the anchors on Apr, 18: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/626/commits/71e4b3179c7e4d5cd6d61270854d31e74a2264ef, and fixed a bug with their positions with boxed elements.

So the easy solution for your installation is to use the long names: `north`, `west`, and so on.