# I Install TexLive from Source and Want to Upgrade Package Circuitikz Manually, how?

Tags: texlive, circuitikz

I install from source Texlive into this directory `/opt/texlive`

[image: 1]

version 2021.
[image: 2]

It is a Linux OS.

I want to upgrade Circuitikz package manually, without using `tlmgr` because **I have no internet in this OS.** I ask this using another OS with internet.

This is the source for Circuitikz that I just downloaded and want to extract / make install manually.

https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/releases/tag/v1.6.3

The question is how? Where are all Tex packages usually located? e.g. Python is usually at `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

Do I just need to type `make` after extracting that Circuitikz at just any directory?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017/36296 (but be aware that not all current package versions will work with an old 2021 kernel/dependencies)

Comment: (if you would like a new texlive without internet, you could use the iso image from https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html)

Comment: I am reading it, when I find how I will post in this forum, it can help others. I port the OS into dual boot, and make it disconnected to internet so I can focus on studying and type Latex. Thanks a lot for the suggestion and info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per any package in CTAN style, the best option is to download the `.tds` zip, and unzip it under your local texmf directory, see [method 3 here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system/73017#73017).

For `circuitikz`, you can also use the `...git` hack following the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524329/38080).

A recent `circuitikz` *should* work with the 2001 distribution, but notice that this is not always a safe thing to do. The LaTeX kernel is evolving rapidly, and although I try to maintain backward compatibility, forward compatibility is not always guaranteed. Notice that if you had internet, updating `circuitikz` with a TeXLive 2021 will give you version 1.4.2 --- you can check it on overleaf easily with the following code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\today{}:
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \LaTeX & \fmtversion \\
    %pdftex & \pdftextversion \\
    Tikz:& \pgfversion & \pgfversiondate\\
    Pgfplots:& \pgfplotsversion & \pgfplotsversiondate \\
    Circuitikz:& \pgfcircversion & \pgfcircversiondate\\
    siunitx: & \csname ver@siunitx.sty\endcsname
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which with TeXLive 2021 gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try it and report it if it is working.

Comment: It works, I just need to know where is the current Circuitikz `tex` and `doc` in this OS located then by replacing it is done.

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess As I commented below, the recommended way is to use the `LOCALTEXMF` directory (do not change the distribution ones!). In this case, it works because there are no new files or files that change names; otherwise, it will break... unless you rebuild the databases.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to upgrade Circuitikz package in Linux OS without using `tlmgr` or internet at all (provided that TexLive has been installed and working).

I use TexStudio and check with package help at the menu, I obtain the location for the `doc` and `latex` for the package `Circuitikz`:

[image: 1]

See that the version is still 1.3.2 (I get the code from @Rmano above)

then I downloaded from CTAN the newest Circuitikz package in zip and extract / unzip it there will be 2 folders `doc` and `tex`, now replace the whole `doc` and `latex` folder in this path (the path to circuitikz in my Linux OS):

```
/opt/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz (replace with the downloaded files inside the doc folder)

/opt/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/circuitikz (replace with the downloaded files inside the tex folder)
```

Now, by using the code to check version, I run and compile again.. et voila.. **the version is 1.6.3**. Thanks a lot.

[image: 3]

Comment: Putting them in the `texmf-dist` is not a good idea. An update/restore of the package will overwrite it. You should put it in `texmf-local` (I linked the relevant post in my answer), which has precedence anyway.

Comment: I tried to put it in `texmf-local`, but it works by putting them in `texmf-dist`