Spark Gap in Circuit Package and Voltage Arrow Capacitor
I have a question about the Circuit Package. Is it possible to create a spark gap from two spheres like in the attached picture? I couldn't find the symbol in the documentation. And my second question is: Is it possible to reverse the voltage drop at C_1? I tried the invert command, but it only works for sources.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}

\draw
  (0,0) node[ground]{} to[C, l=$C_1$, v = $U_{0}$] (0,3)
  to[ammeter] (4,3)   
  to[european resistor,l=$R_2$] (4,0) 
  (4,3) to[european resistor,l=$R_3$] (8,3)
  to [C, l=$C_2$, v = $U_{c}(t)$] (8,0) -- (0,0);
  
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}

Thank you and best regards
Philipp

circuitikz provides a sparkgap component. By default, it displays

You can customize it, for example with
\ctikzset{
  sparkgap end arrow={Circle[scale=2, open]},
  sparkgap/gap=0.3
}

you'll get

Label, voltage and current position and direction can be set with a combination of </> (for the direction) and ^/_ (for the position) before =. Use for example
v^<= $U_{c}(t)$

(caution, no space after v).
Full example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{
  sparkgap end arrow={Circle[scale=2, open]},
  sparkgap/gap=0.3
}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}

\draw
  (0,0) node[ground]{} to[C, l=$C_1$, v = $U_{0}$] (0,3)
  to[sparkgap] (4,3)
  to[european resistor,l=$R_2$] (4,0)
  (4,3) to[european resistor,l=$R_3$] (8,3)
  to [C, l_=$C_2$, v^<= $U_{c}(t)$] (8,0) -- (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



Thank you for your help. Do I have to install a package in Overleaf? Because i recieve this  Error message. I am using the latest Tex Live Version 2024 in Overleaf. "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/sparkgap end arrow', to which you passed 'Circle[scale=2, open]', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

The spark gap was added in the circuitikz version 1.6.9, released on 2024-05-25.

@philbill Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that

As per today, Overleaf comes with 1.6.7

okay thank you for your help :)
