# Can't draw Plain mono amp with Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, overleaf

I want to draw a "plain mono amp" in my circuitikz schematic, but I keep getting this error :

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/plain mono amp' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

I triple checked the manual, this key is supposed to exist, and I don't get what I am actually doing wrong. I am using Overleaf by the way, which should have the latest package of Circuitikz.

Here is an example of what is not working :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[plain mono amp]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Overleaf doesn't have the latest version of `circuitikz`, they're still on TeX Live 2019, on my system with TeX Live 2020 your MWE works fine. You'll need to upload the last version to your project, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that/524329#524329 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521545/draw-flip-flop-with-circuitikz

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much, for some reason I assumed that overleaf used the latest CTAN packages...

Comment: Well, the answer does indeed answer my question, but the question is somewhat different, since I was not aware that I did not have the right version of circuitikz...